# Plot three images horizontally in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, subplot, suptitle

I'm trying to plot three images with their subtitles above them but nothing is showing right now.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('kids.tif')

# Averaged environment
avg_blur = cv2.blur(img,(5,5))
# Gaussian filter
gauss_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(0,0),5)
# Median filter
median_blur = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=3)
axarr[0].imshow(img)
axarr[1].imshow(avg_blur)
axarr[2].imshow(gauss_blur)

"""
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Original')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(avg_blur),plt.title('Averaged environment')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
"""
```

Comment: Add `plt.show()` at the end. It will work. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg' # 'svg', 'retina'
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

# Make dummy data for the image
a = np.arange(25**2).reshape(25,25)

# Show subplots | shape: (1,3) 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12,4))
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flatten()):
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.imshow(a**(i+1), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
    #plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Image: {}'.format(i+1))

#plt.tight_layout()
plt.suptitle('Overall Title')
plt.show()
```

**Output**:
[image]

### Code Similar to Your Implementation

It is easier to just set the current axis `plt.sca(ax)` and then plot as if you have just one subplot to deal with. This makes your code easy to modify and if need be, swiftly move into a loop.

```py
f, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=3)
plt.sca(axarr[0]); 
plt.imshow(img); plt.title('title 1')
plt.sca(axarr[1]); 
plt.imshow(avg_blur); plt.title('title 2')
plt.sca(axarr[2]); 
plt.imshow(gauss_blur); plt.title('title 3')
plt.show()
```

### References

- https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html

Comment: @Arturo Thank you for selecting it as the `accepted` answer. Please consider **`upvoting`** the answer.

Comment: I like it better in the way I have it in the comment, without the coordinates. Can you show it like that?

Comment: Added a section, hope this would help you.

Comment: See the examples here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html.